# How to deal with heavy traffic due to a continuous image stream?

Tags: networking, stream, traffic

I've got this app idea, and it involves a continuous stream of images sent by users. Every user is shown the current image, and as soon as a user sends in a new image, everyone should see the new image where the old used to be. Images are sent in kind of like snapchat, or even faster and simpler than that. Now imagine 1000+ or even 50.000+ people doing this at the same time! Something like 1 new picture every SECOND, that has to be pushed to 50.000+ devices!
How on earth could I manage such traffic? It seems kind of impossible, and this is a very vague question, but I thought I would ask here before scrapping the idea or settling for a compromise.

Answer (score 0):

check out [Build realtime Applications](http://firehose.io/)
 this should help you.